# How to update/delegate table data on AJAX callback jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm making a live update from database using a timer, if new data are found and returned from AJAX call. The data should be added to table if not already there.

But even tho I'm checking the IDs. The same values are added over and over again for every loop. When I'm using console.log i get undefined values and the delete button woun't work. Is there a way to delegate the table on the AJAX return? or is there some other option to make sure same values are not added twize.

**the code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){

        var data = ({
            'id':1
        });

        $.post("ajax.php", data, function(result){

            //get all ids in table
            var arr = [];
            $('.table tr').each(function (i, v) {
                arr.push($(this).data('id'));
            });

            //loop trough all results from ajax call
            $.each(result, function( index, value ){

                //add to table if id dossent exist
                if(jQuery.inArray(value.id, arr) == -1){
                    //add the new value to table
                    $('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>'+value.id+'</td><td>'+value.name+'</td><td>'+value.email+'</td><td>'+value.date+'</td><td><button data-id="'+value.id+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td></tr>');
                }
            });

        },"json");

    },3000);
});
```

Comment: You should add the data attribute on the `<tr>` element like this: `$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr data-id="' + value.id + '"><td>...`. About the delete button we need to see some more of your code to help you out. How are you binding the click event?

Comment: There is no click event, just a ajax timer to fetches from DB, and adds new values to the table. But how do i bind new elements on table on ajax update, its not any good examples on binding.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5wbmw9q/1/) with some mock data, but when you run you'll see that it only adds 10 rows and when you click the delete button it will remove the row. It's the same as your code but with minor adjustments. I think you'll be able to understand what I did.

Comment: it seams that the new data-id thats beeing added to the row, dont get accounted for in the array and show up like: undefined. ideas on how to get the id on ajax to be added to the array?